# how to use htaccess to disguise filetypes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file-type

I want to be able to name my files with whatever extension I choose. In this case let’s use *.foo*, and then process them as PHP files.

Right now my .htaccess looks like this

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .foo
```

But it doesn’t work, it still prompts me to download the file when I access it.

Any advice or tips?

Comment: This question would be better for ServerFault, but try looking at mod_rewrite for apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
rewriteengine on
rewriterule ^(.*)\.foo$ $1.php
```

Comment: no success, should i have anything else in the htaccess file?

Comment: Ya sorry you need rewriteengine on (if you are using other rewriterules it will probably already be set)

Answer (score 2):

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

The syntax looks right to me .. Did you try rebooting the web server?

Also, are there any other settings in .htaccess file working? I mean just make sure that this file is being parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

And then below it:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .foo`

If it does not works try this code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|foo)$">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DefaultLanguage en-US
</FilesMatch>
```

If you want to you can add the `addtype` inside the `<filesmatch>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite the requests of `*.foo` to `*.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1.php
```

This rule will rewrite any request that’s URL path ends on `.foo` internally to the equivalent `.php` URL path.